# aborting kafka reassign partition action

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm using kafka 0.8.2 & one of my kafka servers died (no way to recover the data on the disks). There is a topic, with replication of 1, with one of the partitions on the dead server. I thought a reassignment would move the metadata for that partition to a new server without needing the data, but the reassignment is stuck to `in progress`.

I ran:

```
$ /opt/kafka/kafka/bin/kafka-reassign-partitions.sh --zookeeper myzookeeper.my.com --reassignment-json-file new_assignment.json --verify
Status of partition reassignment:
Reassignment of partition [topicX,1] is still in progress
```

This will never succeed since the dead server is never coming back.

In the new server's log, I saw:

```
[2015-05-28 06:25:15,401] INFO Completed load of log topicX-1 with log end offset 0 (kafka.log.Log)
[2015-05-28 06:25:15,402] INFO Created log for partition [topicX,1] in /mnt2/data/kafka with properties {segment.index.bytes -> 10485760, file.delete.delay.ms -> 60000, segment.bytes -> 536870912, flush.ms -> 9223372036854775807, delete.retention.ms -> 86400000, index.interval.bytes -> 4096, retention.bytes -> -1, min.insync.replicas -> 1, cleanup.policy -> delete, unclean.leader.election.enable -> true, segment.ms -> 604800000, max.message.bytes -> 1000012, flush.messages -> 9223372036854775807, min.cleanable.dirty.ratio -> 0.5, retention.ms -> 259200000, segment.jitter.ms -> 0}. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2015-05-28 06:25:15,403] WARN Partition [topicX,1] on broker 4151132: No checkpointed highwatermark is found for partition [topicX,1] (kafka.cluster.Partition)
[2015-05-28 06:25:15,405] INFO [ReplicaFetcherManager on broker 4151132] Removed fetcher for partitions  (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherManager)
[2015-05-28 06:25:15,408] INFO [ReplicaFetcherManager on broker 4151132] Added fetcher for partitions List() (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherManager)
[2015-05-28 06:25:15,411] INFO [ReplicaFetcherManager on broker 4151132] Removed fetcher for partitions  (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherManager)
[2015-05-28 06:25:15,413] INFO [ReplicaFetcherManager on broker 4151132] Added fetcher for partitions List() (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherManager)
```

Is there a way to force it to complete or abort the reassignment action?

Answer (score 10):

You can abort the assignment by deleting the "/admin/reassign_partitions" zk node on your zookeeper cluster using zookeeper shell, and move the partitions that are assigned to the dead broker to new nodes.

Comment: I ended up booting another machine with the same broker id to finish the partition reassignment

Comment: this works quite well. doesn't hurt to restart the brokers afterwards.

Comment: could you please be more precise, are you talking about the zookeeper shell, are you talking about a directory on the zookeeper?

Comment: @s1mmel  updated the answer on using zookeeper shell to remove the zk path

Comment: for the sake of brevity, here's the full command (should be run from within a zookeeper node): `/your/path/to/bin/zkCli.sh -server localhost:2181/kafka delete /admin/reassign_partitions`

Answer (score 3):

You could enable unclean leader election on all your Kafka nodes and then the reassignment should finish properly.

I have applied with success this procedure for a cluster of 4 Kafka nodes and 3 zookeeper nodes for the topics `__consumer_offsets` having replica node that was decommissioned.

1. Start the reassignment to replica that exists
2. Set `unclean.leader.election.enable=true` and restart each Kafka node of your cluster
3. The reassignment should be finished, you could check with '--verify' flag each reassignment should `completed successfully`
4. Revert to `unclean.leader.election.enable=false` and restart all Kafka nodes

The idea comes from [Move partitions from invalid leader](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Move-partitions-from-invalid-leader/td-p/43334).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I don't have a kafka cluster to test this on. If someone else can try this & upvote his answer, that'll be great. TIA

Comment: Actually I applied it on a real cluster with success, I have added details in the answer.

Comment: this does take more work if you have a huge kafka cluster to restart

Comment: Indeed. I guess it could be enough on the replicas on the topic in reassignment.

Comment: Thanks @NicolasHenneaux this fix drastically reduces reassignment time. Although the elected leaders might not be as in sync as they can be. Good strategy though !

Comment: I want to explain a bit of caveat here. This doesn't work if you have unclean enabled already or The success of these steps depend on restarting the cluster during reassignment with unclean election.

Answer (score 1):

With **kafka 0.8.2.2**, just to confirm Foo L's answer, relaunching another machine with the same broker id solved the issue.

While we don't have this new broker with the same broker id, the migration is paused, and the `verify` command will always give the same answer

`./bin/kafka-reassign-partitions.sh --zookeeper "$ZK_SERVERS" --broker-list "$BROKERS_ID" --reassignment-json-file reassignment.json --verify`

Result:

`Reassignment of partition [topicName,partitionId] is still in progress`